# How to prevent flask-security to auto login after registration?

Tags: flask, flask-security

When a user is registered, I do not want the user to log in automatically, instead the page should redirect to the login page.
Here are my configs:

```
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE'] = False
app.config['SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL'] = False
app.config['USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL'] = False
app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW'] = '/'
app.config['SECURITY_POST_REGISTER_VIEW'] = '/login_redirect/'
```

Below is the /login_redirect/ route defination

```
@app.route('/login_redirect/')
@login_required
def login_redirect():
    return redirect(url_for('security.login'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`logout_user()`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html?highlight=logout_user#flask_security.utils.logout_user) and then do your redirect.

```
from flask_security.utils import logout_user

@app.route('/login_redirect/')
@login_required
def login_redirect():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('security.login'))
```